# How to delete message once it's consumed in case durable subscription is checked in IBM BPM?

Tags: ibm-bpm

Is there a way to delete message once its consumed by IME with durable subscription checked?
In my use case i have a process which has step to wait for IME with durable subscription checked to progress. Now i run the instance p1 and fire an event e1, when p1 reaches IME step it will consume message e1 and progress to next step. But now i have to cancel the p1 instance and reinitiate p2 with same business data. As the correlation value for IME is same for p1 and p2 , p2 will not wait on IME step and consume e1 again as it was having durable subscription checked. This is defeating the purpose as i want p2 to wait for new event e2. So is there any way to delete e1 when it is consumed by p1?

Answer (score 0):

In IBM BPM use the BPMDeleteDurableMessages wsadmin command to delete the durable messages.

See this documentation
 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFTBX_8.5.6/com.ibm.wbpm.ref.doc/topics/rref_bpmdeletedurablemessages.html

Remember for expected and proper use of durable subscriptions, the matching correlation keys should be unique. And second, regular clean up of the messages is important for UCA perforamance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check both Consume message and Durable subscription. Once one UCA is fired and you have checked Consume message then it won't go further. It will consume by that UCA and will wait on the next token to receive another event.